# Simple Templated Dijit throwing empty parse error

Tags: dojo

Sometime I really wonder I don't just use jQuery...

Basic Templated Dijit:

```
define([
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'dijit/_WidgetBase',
    'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
    'dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin',
    'dojo/text!./templates/basic.html'
    ],
function(
    declare,
    _WidgetBase,
    _TemplatedMixin,
    _WidgetsInTemplate,
    template
    ) {
    return declare("Slider", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplate], {
        templateString : template
    })
})
```

The Template:

```
<div class="${baseClass}">
    <div data-role="decor" data-dojo-type="gs/ImageBox/ImageBox">
        <header>
            <h2>Air Jordan 6</h2>
            <h6>2000</h6>
        </header>
        <footer>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-role="toggle">More Information</a>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <section class="data">
            <header>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-role="toggle" class="sticky">Hide</a>
                <ul class="list_info">
                    <li><span>Release Date</span><span>3.15.2003</span></li>
                    <li><span>Release Type</span><span>General Release</span></li>
                    <li><span>Cost at release</span> <span>$100</span></li>
                    <li><span>Cost Today</span> <span>$325-$600</span></li>
                </ul>
            </header>
            <!--
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" href="./php/info.php?id=3"></div>
            -->
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Throws a generic parse error. If I remove the `data-dojo-type="gs/ImageBox/ImageBox"` declaration it at least parses.

Dojo config:

```
<script>
dojoConfig = {
    parseOnLoad : false,
    async : true,
    cacheBust : true,
    packages : [
        { name : 'gs', location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]*$/, '/js') }
    ],
    debug : true,
    debugAtAllCosts : true
}
</script>
```

It'd be awesome if Dojo threw an error with some information, but it just gives a `parse error()` on line 22 of dojo.js.

Driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first line of the post should have read "I don't know why I'm so `(blind|stupid)`".

The first line of the template *actually* had a comment as the first line.  Big no-no apparently.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to tell the AMD loader that you need `gs/ImageBox/ImageBox`.

```
define([
  'dojo/_base/declare',
  'dijit/_WidgetBase',
  'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
  'dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin',
  'gs/ImageBox/ImageBox',
  'dojo/text!./templates/basic.html'
], function(
   declare,
  _WidgetBase,
  _TemplatedMixin,
  _WidgetsInTemplate,
  ImageBox,
  template
) {
```

Comment: Tried that too. I should add that it throws the error with any Dijit, content pane, anything. I've written templates dijits before, but it's super awesome that the error is so generic. I traced it back to the onload method of parser.js in the console, but.. No idea.